# $locationChangeStart acting differently than I expect it to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I configured my routeProvider like this:

```
.when('/countries', {
  templateUrl: 'countries.html',
  controller: 'CountriesController'
})
```

so when I go to `/countries` CountriesController will load and the first thing it does is get a list of countries by sending an $http request to an API.

everything works so far.

Now, when a user tries to go another link, I first want to confirm whether they are sure and if no preventDefault():

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    var response = confirm('Sure?');

    if(!response){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

preventDefault is working but the content brought by $http request disappears.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    var response = confirm('Sure?');

```
if(!response){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

});

check what you getting from response variable